# How to compare regression models with different number of independent variables for a large sample size?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, degrees-of-freedom

I want to do multiple regression and I have a very large sample size for my data. How can I compare models with different numbers of independent variables when the number of independent variables seems almost irrelevant for large $n$ regarding significance, with the number of degrees of freedom being calculated as $n-p-1$. Won't the model with more independent variables always give me a better fit, even if the independent variables used are not even relevant?

To be more precise: I am only interested in the significance of one specific independent variable in the model and want to introduce further variables to explain variance. The t-value required for significance of my parameter of interest is pretty much the same, whether I use 1 other independet variable or 10, since my $n$ is so large. So when introducing enough parameters in the model, even if they don't make any sense, I always see significance for the parameter of interest. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is there a need to work around this?

If you are interested in the coefficient of a specific variable of interest, you are correct in adding potential [confounders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) in order to reduce [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias).

If the coefficient is significant in all specifications of the regression, this can be seen as a good indicator that the variable of interest indeed is associated with the outcome.

However, the fact that with very large data, coefficients tend to be always significant, illustrates that significance may not be the best statistical property to analyse the relation between the outcome and the variable of interest. Perhaps you should look at effect sizes (via calculation of standardized coefficients) and effect sizes in subgroups (via interaction terms).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from what you described but you seem to be introducing variables in a stepwise fashion.   This will invalidate inference for the parameter of interest.   Pre-specify the full model you think best reflects the situation and estimate the parameter of interest from that one model.  With regard to your original question, consider the use of AIC and in the model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic minus total model degrees of freedom.  These are both penalized for model complexity.  AIC effectively penalizes for twice the degrees of freedom whereas the other measure is just corrected for chance associations.